# BasicTabbedPaneUI paint html text

Tags: java, swing

i would extend the `BasicTabbedPaneUi` so i can design my own tabPane.  I have one problem with the html text, is to set the color of the text once the tab is selected.  I override the paintText method with the following, almost the same code as the orignal method:

```
@Override
protected void paintText(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, Font font, FontMetrics metrics, int tabIndex, String title, Rectangle textRect, boolean isSelected) {
    g.setFont(font);

    View v = getTextViewForTab(tabIndex);
    if (v != null) {
        // html
        Color fg = tabPane.getForegroundAt(tabIndex);
        if (isSelected && (fg instanceof UIResource)) {
            Color selectedFG = UIManager.getColor(
                    "TabbedPane.selectedForeground");
            if (selectedFG != null) {
                fg = selectedFG;
            }
        }
        v.paint(g, textRect);
    } else {
        // plain text
        int mnemIndex = tabPane.getDisplayedMnemonicIndexAt(tabIndex);

        if (tabPane.isEnabled() && tabPane.isEnabledAt(tabIndex)) {
            Color fg = tabPane.getForegroundAt(tabIndex);
            if (isSelected && (fg instanceof UIResource)) {
                Color selectedFG = UIManager.getColor(
                        "TabbedPane.selectedForeground");
                if (selectedFG != null) {
                    fg = selectedFG;
                }
            }
            g.setColor(fg);
            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(tabPane, g,
                    title, mnemIndex,
                    textRect.x, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent());

        } else { // tab disabled
            g.setColor(tabPane.getBackgroundAt(tabIndex).brighter());
            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(tabPane, g,
                    title, mnemIndex,
                    textRect.x, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent());
            g.setColor(tabPane.getBackgroundAt(tabIndex).darker());
            SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(tabPane, g,
                    title, mnemIndex,
                    textRect.x - 1, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent() - 1);

        }
    }
}
```

In the case we have html text for the tab, it v is not null.  If i set a color to the graphics object used in the paint method it does not change the text color.
I use html because i want to have my tab's text on two lines.
Thanks for helping changing the color.

Comment: What happens when you set the HTML [color](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32) attribute?

Comment: It works when i set it directly in the html tag, but how can i change it when the tab is selected ?

Answer (score 1):

I would be reluctant to develop a custom [`TabbedPaneUI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/TabbedPaneUI.html) unless it were part of a complete Look & Feel implmentation.

Instead, consider a custom tab component, as shown in [`TabComponentsDemo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#eg) and discussed in [*How to Use Tabbed Panes*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html). This will give you absolute control over the component's appearance, without sacrificing compatibility with the user's chosen Look & Feel.